# $a_{n}^{2} + a_{n} = 4S_{n} + 3 \ （n \geqslant 1）$，find $a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Set sequence $a_{n} > 0(n \geqslant 1)$.$S_{n}$ is the sum of the preceding $n$ terms of the sequence $a_{n}$
and satisfies $a_{n}^{2} + a_{n} = 4S_{n} + 3$.

1)Find the general term formula of sequence $a_{n}$;

2)$b_{n} \overset{\text{def}}{=} \frac{1}{a_{n}a_{n+1}}$.
Find the sum of the preceding $n$ entries of the sequence $b_{n}$.

Through the conditions, I could get the following formulas

\begin{align}
    a_{n+1}^{2} + a_{n+1} = 4S_{n+1} + 3 \ \ \ \ (1)\\
    a_{n}^{2} + a_{n} = 4S_{n} + 3 \ \ \ \ (2)
\end{align}

By $(1) - (2)$,I have got $a_{n+1}^2 - 3a_{n+1} = a_{n}^2 + a_{n}$,but I couldn't continue.

Comment: Just for clarity, is $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i$, or $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i$?

Comment: Since $S_1=a_1$, one can find that $a_1=\frac{1}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{21}\right)$, and then that $a_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{45+8 \sqrt{21}}\right)$ ... are you sure the equation is correct?

Comment: Why don't you answer to Keen-ameteur ? Your question is indeed ambiguous.

Comment: I have shown that $n \geqslant 1$,so $S_{n}$ should be $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$.@Keen-ameteur

Comment: I'm sure I copied the question right.But I couldn't prove that there was not a general term formula of this sequence ,either.@GregMartin

Comment: This is a non-linear recurrence, and not of any of the solvable forms (as far as I know).